# Getting Email Configuration from D2 Config with D2FS

Tags: documentum, emc

I would like to know how to get the Email Configuration from D2 using D2FS. I need the information that I set within the D2 Config that I set in Tools >> Email.

Thanks.

Comment: D2FS is the programming part of it... I would like to know how to get some informations using D2FS...

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, although it may help if you add any code that you've tried already (if you haven't tried any code, you should really search for it instead of using Stackoverflow). It helps the community answer your question in more detail :-).

Comment: Yes, i searched a lot for it, but seems that i cannot make it, this is why i created this post. The documentation is very limited and don´t have so many posts about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i researched, there is no D2FS service (D2 4.1.0) that allows me to retrieve this information. What i can make is to use DFC or DFS to read instances of d2_mail_config.